# R: why are the while and for loops different in terms of the accessibility of the loop index/counter from within the loop body?

Tags: r, for-loop, while-loop, control-flow

Consider the following toy examples in R:

```
#For loop
i <- 1
for(i in 1:10){
  print(i)
  if(i == 5){
    i <- 8
    next
  }
}

#For loop output
[1] 1
[1] 2
[1] 3
[1] 4
[1] 5
[1] 6
[1] 7
[1] 8
[1] 9
[1] 10

#While loop
i <- 1
while (i <= 10){
  print(i)
  if(i == 5){
    i <- 8
    next
  }
  i <- i + 1
}

#While loop output
[1] 1
[1] 2
[1] 3
[1] 4
[1] 5
[1] 8
[1] 9
[1] 10
```

In both examples above, upon a conditional statement within the loop body being evaluated as being `TRUE` (`if(i == 5)`), there is an attempt to alter the loop index/counter. However, this only seems to work in the `while` loop and not in the `for` loop.

Why is this the case?

More specifically, `?control` has this to say about the `for` loop's index (`var` in the quote below):

> You can assign to var within the body of the loop, but this will not
>   affect the next iteration.

Why is this a necessity for the `for` construct but not the `while` construct?

Answer (score 3):

From `help('for')`. My emphasis:

> **The seq in a `for` loop is evaluated at the start of the loop; changing
>   it subsequently does not affect the loop.** If seq has length zero the
>   body of the loop is skipped. Otherwise the variable `var` is assigned in
>   turn the value of each element of seq. **You can assign to `var` within
>   the body of the loop, but this will not affect the next iteration.**
>   When the loop terminates, `var` remains as a variable containing its
>   latest value.

What you have discovered is documented behavior.

As for `while` loops, there is no evaluation *of a variable `var`* ahead of its use because there is no variable to evaluate. `while` loops may not have counters at all, they depend on a condition, evaluated every time the loop reaches it.

Answer (score 0):

Because `for` will loop over each elements in the input vector. What happens if you assign the variable to a value not in the input vector? The loop structure in `R` is different to what we are used to in e.g. `C`, this is the choice of implementation they made.